# Automated incrementing of the version values in TFS

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, gitlab

I need to Automated increment of the version values in TFS. When I checking my code in TFS, I need to control my Version number automatically. How can i do this in TFS.

Comment: Are you using TFVC or Git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good practice to automatically increment the version number as each version number has a semantic meaning indicating the degree of change compared to the previous version. In order to somehow perform that automatically, you would need some kind of complicated software to asses the type of code change compared to previous version, and this still wouldn't be guaranteed to identify the change correctly every time.

Normally version numbers are constructed in this format: Major.Minor.Patch.Revision.Build

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your answer, I want to increase the major and minor number automatically. How can i do this.